# A virtual smart card implementation

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm currently trying to write an application that should fool an OS into believing there's a PKCS#11 compliant smartcard plugged in, and then forward PKCS#11 requests to a server.
I stumbled upon this project https://frankmorgner.github.io/vsmartcard/virtualsmartcard/README.html which looks promising, but i was wondering if there was an easier solution to do so ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you really need a virtual smart card? It is probably much simpler to implement the pkcs11 interface using your server as a backend (and it makes more sense)...

Comment: Much simpler indeed ^^. My supervisor agreed to the implementation of the pkcs#11 interface in a DLL, which makes my life so much easier. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You might have to "lie" a bit if the PKCS#11 is asked if you are a HW device, and provide some token insertion/removal tricks. But otherwise no HW required. PKCS#11 is a C based API which explicitly allows software implementations.

Comment: I mostly planned to play with the token/session/slot flags to fool the applications using the library regarding token events (insertion/removal and such). Otherwise it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

(Transcript of discussion in comments)

You do not need a virtual smart card to implement a PKCS#11 provider.

All you need is to develop a library implementing the [PKCS#11 API](https://www.oasis-open.org/standards#pkcs11-base-v2.40) which leverages your server.

The clients then can use this library as any other PKCS#11 provider.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are several PKCS#11 proxies: https://github.com/ANSSI-FR/caml-crush for example or have a look here: https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/graphene#related

And repeating the mantra: there's no such thing as "PKCS#11 compatible smart card" the same way there is no "PC/SC compatible smart card reader". Both are host-side software API-s that have no relation to the hardware implementation.

Comment: There are indeed no fully PKCS#11 compliant smart cards because a smart card has APDU's as interface, but it is of course possible to mimic PKCS#11 functionality.

Comment: "... there is no "PC/SC compatible smart card reader" sorry, but that's plain wrong. For USB for instance, you might want a CCID compliant device. Otherwise you'd need a PCSC compatible driver to be delivered *with* the card reader. The availability of this driver would indicate if the reader is PCSC compatible or not.

Comment: Correct, there are *CCID* compatible smart card readers, but no matter what MS is implying, there's no such thing as "PC/SC" compatible *readers* (without drivers)